# what is the correct way to read a csv file into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a data analysis project and while importing the csv file into spyder I am facing this error. Please help me to debug this as I am new to programming.

```
#import library 
>>>import pandas as pd 
#read the data from from csv as a pandas dataframe 
>>>df = pd.read.csv('/Documents/Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv')
```

This is the error shown when I use the pd.read.csv command:

> ```
> File "C:/Users/mylaptop/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 4, in <module>
>     df = pd.read_csv('/Documents/Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv')
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read'
> ```

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` not `pd.read.csv` please go through the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @anky_91 will solve your issue. Also if I may, try to define absolute paths using os.getcwd etc. for the file path to avoid invalid path issues.

Answer (score 1):

you should use :

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Documents/Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv')
```

see here [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `pandas.read_csv()` instead of `pandas.read.csv()` the error is litterally  telling you this method doesn't exist .

Comment: Thanks @ahmed Xeros. it was a great help